# VSCode mapping Ctrl-numpad4 vs Alt-numpad4

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently, I have two mappings in `keybindings.json` thus:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+numpad4",
    "command": "editor.action.revealDeclaration"
},
{
    "key": "alt+numpad4",
    "command": "editor.action.revealDeclaration"
}
```

The idea is to essentially navigate from a function's definition to a function's declaration. `Ctrl+numpad4` works just fine. `Alt+numpad4` also works, except that once it goes to the function's declaration, it displays a black diamond symbol `♦`

See gif which will demonstrate that first, `Ctrl+numpad4` works, and then, `Alt+numpad` works but only after it enters the diamond symbol.

[image]

Is there a way to turn this off ?

Comment: Probably not, alt then numpad is the standard way of inserting ASCII character codes

Comment: https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/number-four-ascii-code-52.html does indeed indicate that Alt+numpad4 gives a "diamonds card suit". I do have other alt+numpad mappings, but if the focus goes to a nontextual area, where nothing is printed, it works. For instance, I have alt+numpad6 to go to the call stack, even though it should display a "red spade" card.